# sqlite (android) update extremely slow

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this table in android sqlite:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + IMAGE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_FULL_PATH + " TEXT UNIQUE, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_FOLDER + " TEXT, " +
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_IMAGE_NAME + " TEXT, " +
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE + " INTEGER, " +
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_IS_PROCESSED + " INTEGER, " +
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_PROCESS_ORDER + " INTEGER, " +
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_DATE_PHOTO_TAKEN + " INTEGER, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_ORIENTATION + " INTEGER, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_WIDTH + " INTEGER, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_HEIGHT + " INTEGER, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_RATING + " INTEGER, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_SIZE + " INTEGER, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_CAMERA_MODEL + " TEXT, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_CAMERA_MAKE + " TEXT, " + 
                                                       TABLE_IMAGE_COLUMN_MICRO_THUMBNAIL + " BLOB) ");
```

When I try to exec simple update statement:

```
update Image set IsProcessed=1
```

It takes around 20 seconds. This looks waaaaaay to slow to me.

Here are couple of remarks that could be useful:

- database is on sdcard
- BLOB field is filled with items of around 2-4kb
- number of items in table is around 450

Any help how to speed things up would be much appreciated.

Comment: I observe the same slowness when setting blob data in a table.